# How does one instruct the ExtractingRequestHandler to parse only the body of a document?

Tags: solr, apache-tika

How can I instruct the extracting request handler to ignore metadata/headers etc. when it constructs the "content" of the document I send to it?

For example, I created an MS Word document containing just the word "SEARCHWORD" and nothing else. However, when I ship this doc to my solr index, its contents are mapped to my "body" field as follows:

```
<str name="body">
    Last-Printed 2009-02-05T15:02:00Z Revision-Number 22 Comments stream_source_info 
    myfile Last-Author Inigo Montoya Template Normal.dotm Page-Count 1 subject Application-Name
     Microsoft Macintosh Word Author Jesus Baggins Word-Count 2 xmpTPg:NPages 1 Edit-Time 
    108600000000 Creation-Date 2008-11-05T20:19:00Z stream_content_type application/octet-stream 
    Character Count 14 stream_size 31232 stream_name /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpHCIg7y 
    Some Company Content-Type application/msword Keywords Last-Save-Date 
    2012-05-01T18:55:00Z SEARCHWORD
</str>
```

All I want is the body of the document, in this case the word "SEARCHWORD."

For further reference, here's my extraction handler:

```
 <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                 startup="lazy"
                 class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="fmap.content">body</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The awesome people on the solr-user mailing list got to the the bottom of this. It turns out the field name "meta" is a special case: the ExtractingRH copies all metadata to this field. In my case, I was getting the contents, too, because of the fmap.contents mapping in my own ERH. I renamed my "meta" field to something else, and now it receives only the contents of the document.

This behavior is not currently documented in the Solr wiki. I hope this helps someone else who may have a field named "meta" in their schema to which they're extracting document contents (unlikely, I know).

Comment: Hi @joadha, very sorry to resurrect such an old answer but I'm stumped with a similar issue. What did you mean with "I renamed my "meta" field to something else"? There seems to be no "meta" field in the extraction handler shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding [XPath param](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#XPath) to defaults:

```
<str name="XPath">/xhtml:body</str>
```

You can quickly test it with url, like the above link shows.

Comment: Would that work with any document I pass? I'm adding Word and PDF documents primarily, and I'm seeking a format-agnostic solution.

Comment: I'm by no means Tika expert, but AFAIK, the XHTML returned by Tika is generalized. Body part is handled by Tika's [BodyContentHandler](http://tika.apache.org/0.7/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html), so I assume the XHTML's tag "Body" is a standard. Try parsing PDF and see what happens ;)